# Name Error: global name 'loader' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I want to fetch a data from models in django . i have a code but there is an name error.
views.py
def news(request):

```
from django import template
    from django.template.loader import get_template 

    template_source_loaders = None
        template = loader.get_template("news.html")
        warning_list = []
        news_list = []
        blog_query = blogs.object.all()

        for news_entry in blog_query:
            news_list.append(news_entry)
        #except Exception, e:
            warning_list.append(e.message)
        context = Context({
            'news_list':news_list,
            'warnings' :warning_list,
            })
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

template:-

```
{%if warnings%}
 {%for warning in warnings%}
   {{warning}}
        {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}
    {%if news_list%}
        {%for news in news_list%}
            {{news.headline}}
            {{news.date}}
            {{news.content}}
            <a href="{{news.author.website}}">{{news.author.author}}</a>
        {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You imported `get_template` from `loader`. This is basic Python, so I suggest you read up a bit more on pure Python before working with Django.

Comment: You are now behaving very badly. Having got an answer to your question, you edit the title to ask another different question. If that weren't bad enough, the cause of the second problem is exactly the same as the first. I've rolled back the edit and will vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code

```
    template = get_template("news.html")
```

instaed of

```
    template = loader.get_template("news.html")
```

Your problem will be solved.Because you have already impotred function get_template so need to use loader.get_template

Comment: Or add the import loader:  `from django.template import loader`